# Rearrange the following differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have the following differential equation $\frac{dN}{dt}=0.1\cdot N(1-\frac{N}{100}) - 5$. Where $N(0)=100$. How do I rearrange this equation to be in the form of $\frac{dN}{dt}=-k((N-A)^2+B)$, where $k, A, B$ are positive constants? I rearranged this equation to be $\frac{dN}{dt}=-0.1 \left(N - \frac{N^2}{1000}\right) - 5$. But I can't get the square. Perhaps I should try completing the square on this one?

Comment: Yes complete the square, also I think it should be $\frac{dN}{dt}=-0.1\left(\frac{N^2}{100}-N\right)-5$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your quadratic in the brackets as $x^2-x = (x-\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4}$